# Basic Authentication with CURL/PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a basic API Authentication using PHP and CURL and I keep getting the error "no Route matched with those values".

Here is what the API docs are telling me to do:

```
curl 'https://api.impact.com/Advertiser/<AccountSID>/Actions' \
-u '<AccountSID>:<AuthToken>'
```

And here is the PHP i'm using to try and do this:

```
$accountSID = 'XXXXX';
$authToken = 'XXXXX';
$url = 'https://api.impact.com/Advertiser/'.$accountSID.'/Actions';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $accountSID.":".$authToken);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You might need to contact the API devs about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's gonna solve your issue but you can try:

```php
$username = 'name';
$password = 'pass';
$headers = array(
    'Method: GET',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($username.':'.$password)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: This gives me the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though, worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

"no Route matched with those values" means your URL and/or method is off. It's not the auth that's faulty, it's the `/Advertiser/<AccountSID>/Actions` part that you should check.

In general, in Web systems where the URL path tree doesn't correspond to the underlying filesystem (like most APIs), routing refers to the process of finding the right handler (e. g. a class or a function) for the provided method and URL path, which in your case is `GET` to `/Advertiser/<AccountSID>/Actions`. I'd rather expect the URL that ends with `Actions` to accept a `POST`, not a `GET`, but you should check with the API docs and/or support.

Depending on how the server is set up, this error may or may not mean that the authentication went fine. A server may run authentication *before* routing, or *after*.

Comment: I tried it with both POST and GET. If I use this endpoint it gives me the same error:

Comment: curl 'https://api.impact.com/Advertisers/<AccountSID>/CompanyInformation' \
  -X GET \
  -u '<AccountSid>:<AuthToken>' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json'

Comment: I guess a better question is how to I translate what the API docs say into valid PHP/CURL 'curl 'https://api.impact.com/Advertisers/<AccountSID>/CompanyInformation' \
  -X GET \
  -u '<AccountSid>:<AuthToken>' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json''

Comment: I know nothing about the Impact API. But the error you are getting is not an auth error. The <AccountSid> is a placeholder, you know that, right? You are expected to provide the SID of a valid account there, without the angle brackets.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a placeholder. I'm using the actual AccountSID without the angle brackets.

Comment: Does the command line curl work, or are you getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the endpoint URL wrong. it should have been

$url = 'https://api.impact.com/Advertisers/'.$accountSID.'/Actions';

instead of

$url = 'https://api.impact.com/Advertiser/'.$accountSID.'/Actions';